# DLookUp Issue(?) In MS Access

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access form, I have this text field "Current Balance" in which it should look up for the  value in the table 'attached' to it.

So, in its Control Source, I have

```
=DLookUp([Balance],"Collections","")
```

It displays the balance from the table. But my problem is, when I go to the next record, the textbox "Current Balance" has a value that is #Error instead of the last value that was has been inputted. How could I address the said issue?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `=Nz(DLookUp("[Balance]","[Collections]",""))` to avoid the #Error. It is most probably caused by a `Null` value.

Comment: I also did try putting NZ, but the #Error is still there when I am going to the next record. But thank you for helping

Comment: Sometimes when there is an unrelated error the DLookUp functions might return the #Error sign. Do you get any other error messages?

Comment: No, its just the #Error when I go to the next record